# Deserializing Json Object of objects in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I've been struggling to get this to work for a while now... So, let's suppose I've got this .json file:

```
{
    "fieldConfs" : 
        {
            "Object1" : {"origin" : "IdArticulo"    , "destinationTable" : "Articulos", "destinationField" : "IdArticulo", "dataType" : "nvarchar"},
            "Object2" : {"origin" : "Nombre"    , "destinationTable" : "Articulos", "destinationField" : "Descrip", "dataType" : "nvarchar"}
        }
}
```

And I want to deserialize it into a list of Objects, so each Object inside "fieldConfs" (Object1, object2) will go into a List.

My code so far is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace modules.dataProcessing.ConfManager
{
    public class Field
    {
        public string Origin { get; set; }

        public string DestinationTable { get; set; }

        public string DestinationField { get; set; }

        public string DataType { get; set; }

    }

    public class FieldConfs
    {
        public string Id
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public IList<Field> Fields
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    public static class JsonTools
    {
        public static List<FieldConfs> loadConf(string json)
        {
            List<FieldConfs> fC = new List<FieldConfs>();
            fC = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FieldConfs>>(json);
            return fC;
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
List<FieldConfs> confs = new List<FieldConfs>();
confs = JsonTools.loadConf(json);
```

I know I'm lacking something, but I'm new to C# and to Json as well and I don't know what it is that I'm missing. Any hint or help would be appreciate it. Thank you all beforehand.

**EDIT:** For a little more clarification, what I'm really asking is for advice on how should I do this, since I'm new.

I'd like to be able to deserialize the json into a list so I can later do in code:

```
foreach (List<FieldConfs> list in confs) {

     // Code for each list where list would be Object1... Object2... 
}
```

So maybe I'm not structuring well my Json... I don't know if I'm explaining myself well...

Comment: any specific error you are getting ?

Comment: `fieldConfs` is probably better off as `Dictionary<string, Field>`. You also need a root object with the `fieldConfs` property.

Comment: Try to deserialize into this: `public class Root { public Dictionary<string, Field> FieldConfs { get; } = new Dictionary<string, Field>(); }` - ie. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was in the .json file, it was not well structured, so I changed it to this:

```
[
    {
        "Id":"IdArticulo",
        "Fields":{"Origin":"IdArticulo","DestinationTable":"Articulos","DestinationField":"IdArticulo","DataType":"nvarchar"}
    },

    {
        "Id":"Nombre",
        "Fields":{"Origin":"Espanol","DestinationTable":"Articulos","DestinationField":"Descrip","DataType":"nvarchar"}
    }
]
```

And changed my C# code a bit and the end result is this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace modules.dataProcessing.ConfManager
{
    public class Fields
    {
        public string Origin { get; set; }

        public string DestinationTable { get; set; }

        public string DestinationField { get; set; }

        public string DataType { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string finalString = "Origin: " + this.Origin + "\n" + "DestinationTable: " + this.DestinationTable + "\n";
            finalString += "DestinationField: " + this.DestinationField + "\n" + "DataType: " + this.DataType;

            return finalString;
        }

    }

    public class FieldConfs
    {
        public string Id
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Fields Fields
        {
            get; set;
        }       

    }

    public static class JsonTools
    {
        public static List<FieldConfs> loadConf(string json)
        {
            List<FieldConfs> fieldConfs = new List<FieldConfs>();

            fieldConfs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FieldConfs>>(json);

            return fieldConfs;
        }

        public static void saveConf(List<FieldConfs> confs, string fileToSave)
        {
            using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(fileToSave))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                // Serializamos el objeto directamente en el stream de datos
                serializer.Serialize(file, confs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am able to serialize the list and deserialize it, thanks anyway for the answers you posted since after reading them I found the ilumination required to solve this.

Thank you all, sincerely.

Comment: The way you use it you can make `FieldConfs.Fields` property simply of type `Field` instead of `List<Field>`.

Comment: Yeah, thats' what I did, I changed my C# code in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the objects as list , then the json should be modified with square brackets which indicate them as a collection of objects .

```
{
    "fieldConfs" : 
        [
             {"origin" : "IdArticulo"    , "destinationTable" : "Articulos", "destinationField" : "IdArticulo", "dataType" : "nvarchar"},
             {"origin" : "Nombre"    , "destinationTable" : "Articulos", "destinationField" : "Descrip", "dataType" : "nvarchar"}
        ]
}
```

Comment: But mind that this results in a `List<Field>` instead of a `List<FieldConfs>`.

Comment: After the deserialization call `FieldConfs fieldConfs = new FieldConfs() { Fields = listOfFields }` where `listOfFields` is the the result of type `List<Field>`.

Comment: Also to get the collection you would have to get the value of `fieldConfs` first (the JSON array). Otherwise the deserialization will fail.

Comment: Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the json into the paste buffer. open a new class in the editor, select 'Paste Special' from the edit menu. It will generate a c# class for the json. Magic.

Comment: For static purposes it does the work, but the creations of those Ids are dynamic, but thanks for your answer.